# Import Type Definition for Express

Tags: flowtype

My controller methods all have the function signature of either `(req, res)` or `(req, res, next)`. I found out that I can use the built-in `http$ClientRequest` and `http$ServerResponse` types from https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/node.js to enable basic type safety on these objects, but I am running into errors with properties that Express adds such as `req.query`. Using `req.query` in flow-code is currently yielding the following error:

```
^^^^ property `query`. Property not found in http$ClientRequest
```

Where can I find the proper type definition for the Express-style request object and how do I bring that into my project?

Answer (score 0):

One solution appears to be to create a union type like this:

```
type ExpressReq = http$ClientRequest & {
    model: any,
    query: any,
    params: any,
}
```

I just stuck that in the same file and it worked.